# LinkedIn API to post Share using php oauth class

Tags: php, linkedin-api

The details:

1. I am using Manuel Lemos php oauth class and the login_with_linkedin.php script as reference.
2. I have successfully gone through the oauth process and retrieved the user's info using the API 'http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~'
3. I get an error when using the Post Shares API (http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares)

Here is the relevent code from my last unsuccessful attempt;

```
// Scope settings

 $client->scope = 'r_fullprofile r_emailaddress r_network rw_nus';

// Call to API (Post)

$success = $client->CallAPI(
  'http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares', 
  'POST', array(
      "format"=>"json",
      "comment"=> "Test"
   ), array('FailOnAccessError'=>true), $user);
```

Here is the error message:

`Error: it was not possible to access the API call: it was returned an unexpected response status 401 Response: { "errorCode": 0, "message": "Unknown authentication scheme", "requestId": "8DWA0EBJTB", "status": 401, "timestamp": 1355774186502 }`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted the same issue on the class creator's forum as well.
He got back to me with an answer that worked.

The answer can be found here:
http://www.phpclasses.org/discuss/package/7700/thread/22/